# No Events Firing on (Plain!) Javascript Multi-select Element

Tags: javascript, events, multi-select

I'm trying to put two multi-select elements on a survey page. One selects workshops a person has attended, the other selects workshops a person wanted to attend but didn't. There's also a button with a listener attached to it that displays rating options for whichever workshop the person selects from the first multi-select. HTML is like so:

```
<table class="edoa-content">
:
:
<td colspan="5" class="edoa-conv-color3">
<label><b>Which workshops/plenary sessions did you attend? (Hold down the control [Cmd on a Mac] button when you click on 
    each item in order to select more than one item from the list):</b></label></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<select tabindex="0" multiple id="wkshp" name="wkshp">
<option style="color: #AC2931; font-weight: bold; font-size: 105%" 
value="bmb">Workshop Name 1 (Workshop Presenter)
</option>
<option style="color: #AC2931; font-weight: bold; font-size: 105%" value="bmb">Workshop Name 2 (Workshop Presenter)
</option>
:
: etc.
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="5" style="text-align: right"><button class="edoa-btnLink" id="btn_wkshp" tabindex="1">Click here to rate the chosen workshops</button></td></tr>
:
:
<tr><td colspan="5" class="edoa-conv-color3">
<label><b>Please select any workshops you wanted to attend, but didn't or couldn't (Hold down the control [Cmd on a Mac] button when you click on each item in order to select more than one item from the list):</b></label></td></tr>
<select tabindex="2" multiple id="wkshpnot" name="wkshpnot">
<option style="color: #AC2931; font-weight: bold; font-size: 105%" value="bmb">Workshop Name 1 (Workshop Presenter)
</option>
<option style="color: #AC2931; font-weight: bold; font-size: 105%" value="bmb">Workshop Name 2 (Workshop Presenter)
</option>
:
: etc.
</select>
</td></tr>
:
:
etc.
```

I'm attaching a listener to both multi-selects (and the button) on load, and the entire page is built by php because I have processing to do before the page actually loads, variables on the page to set, etc. The change listener attached to the first one gets fired just fine, but I can't get any event to fire on the second one. I've tried blur, change, and click and not a one of them fires.

Code for the first listener is:

```
var btn = document.getElementById(otherFld); 
if (btn){
   if(btn.style.display === 'none'){
     var selopts = document.getElementById(elemId).options; 
     var sels = 0;
     for (var i=0; i < selopts.length; ++i){ 
       if (selopts[i].selected){sels++;}
     }
     if (sels > 0){
        var add = confirm("Do you want to add to the list you've chosen or start over?\nPress OK to add, Cancel to start over");
       if (!add){
         remove_element("wkshpTbl");
       } else {
          btn.innerHTML="Please click here to add the workshops to rate";
       }
     }
     btn.style.display='inline';
   }
 }
```

Code for the second listener, at the moment, is just an alert.

I'm not sure what's going on. I've searched this site and googled it and everything I see is either not applicable to this situation or refers to some javascript library, not pure/plain javascript.

Any ideas?

Comment: If your listener isn't working then you need to show the code that relates to that, eg where and how you set the listener

Comment: Actually, I just figured out what the problem is. I didn't have this element in my list of elements to attach listeners to in the page. So I actually wasn't attaching a listener to the element. D'oh!! Thanks!

Comment: So if I'd done what what I was _supposed_ to do, as @PatrickEvans reminded me, I would have seen that and not had to post here at all! But at least I reminded myself how the posting interface works. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out what the problem is. I didn't have this element in my list of elements to attach listeners to in the page. D'oh!!